# Launch SIRI from application

Tags: siri

I see apps on the store (application connected with a BLE button) that can launch SIRI when the BLE button is pressed.(By exemple flic button)
Any idea how this feature could be implemented ?
I did not see any API available to launch SIRI from an app
Did this application uses private APIs ?

This same application can:
- lock the screen when BLE button is pressed
- take screenshots when BLE button is pressed

Answer (score 1):

It's called HID over GATT and is a BLE profile.

Comment: Any information of keyboard event values to be used for iPhone control (home button, simple/double/triple home button click, sound up, sound down, take picture) ?

Comment: @fvisticot did you figure it out?